# Kivy APK Does Not Run on Android Phone

Tags: android, kivy, apk

I have built an APK from the Kivy/Buildozer VM with a very simple program to test it.

here is the Python file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class MyPopup(Popup):
    pass


class Test(Widget):
    pass


class KivyTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


app = KivyTestApp()
app.run()
```

and the Kivy file:

```
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyPopup>:
    title: 'Test'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400

<Test>:
    Button:
        id: but
        size: root.width, root.height
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: .5, .7, .9, 1
        text: 'Press me to open the popup'
        pos: 0, 0
        on_press: Factory.MyPopup().open()
```

When I run the APK of this code, I simply get a black screen. Note: I am not running this in Kivy Launcher. This is a successfully built APK from buildozer.

Comment: what's the name of your kv file? If for some reason it isn't "KivyTest.kv" it will show a black screen instead of your interface. It might just be showing your `Test(Widget)` class which has nothing in it, hence a blank screen. Could check this by maybe doing `Test(Label)` and setting the text to something like "Hello World"

Comment: My kv file's name is `KivyTest.kv` it runs perfectly fine on my computer, just not when it is completely compiled to an APK

Comment: Hmm. If there isn't any crashing going on, it sounds to me like the kv file for some reason isn't being loaded properly. Can you try my suggestion of changing your `Test` class to be like a label or something (do it on the .py side, not the .kv side) and seeing if its text is displayed?

Comment: Sorry, my buildozer is not working now for some reason :( I tried to build this but it did not build

Comment: I was able to successfully do "buildozer android debug deploy run logcat" using your code. Perhaps post your `buildozer.spec` file.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv), the name of the `.kv` file must be all lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `kv` file is named `KivyTest.kv`, your app will not load your `kv` file and the app will be just a blank screen. You must change the name of the file to `kivytest.kv`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv).